# $sanitize / ngsanitize in angular1 + meteor

Tags: angular-meteor

I'm working on a prototype for migrating my angularJs app to meteor + angularJs. 
My old controller code uses `$rootScope`, `$anchorScroll`, `$sanitize`, `$sce`.
But confused how to use them in the meteor + angular 1 class.

I want to use these in the methods defined in the class which are accessed from the template.

Followed the tutorial and created class and in the constructor, provided all the services used in my old app. Example code:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import './SampleTest.html'
import {SampleData} from '../api/data';

class SampleTest {
constructor($stateParams,$scope,$reactive){ 
.....
}

const name = 'sampleTest';

// create a module
export default angular.module(name, [
    angularMeteor,
    uiRouter,
    sanitize,
]).component(name, {
    templateUrl: `imports/ui/apps/test/${name}/${name}.html`,
    controllerAs: name,
    controller: SampleTest
}).config(config);
..
..
```